# How to write/read bits from/to a Stream? (C#)

Tags: c#

How can I write bits to a stream (System.IO.Stream) or read in C#? thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a little more context?  Do you mean read/write binary data as opposed to text data?  What type of data is it that you're intending to read/write?

Comment: Do you really want to write single bits (not bytes)?

Comment: The question is crystal clear, that he needs to write or read a single bit at a time to/from a stream. This is typical for writing compact streams or Huffman compression.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could create an extension method on Stream that enumerates the bits, like this:

```
public static class StreamExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<bool> ReadBits(this Stream input)
    {
        if (input == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("input");
        if (!input.CanRead) throw new ArgumentException("Cannot read from input", "input");
        return ReadBitsCore(input);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<bool> ReadBitsCore(Stream input)
    {
        int readByte;
        while((readByte = input.ReadByte()) >= 0)
        {
            for(int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
                yield return ((readByte >> i) & 1) == 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Using this extension method is easy:

```
foreach(bool bit in stream.ReadBits())
{
    // do something with the bit
}
```

**Attention**: you should not call ReadBits multiple times on the same Stream, otherwise the subsequent calls will forget the current bit position and will just start reading the next byte.

Comment: Neat using extension methods. However, you could add support for reading bits in opposite order.

Comment: Multiple calls to `ReadBits` will read a new byte from the stream every time, even if there are unread bits from the previous byte. I've posted an answer below which takes care of this.

Comment: Yeah, should have a flag for endianess.

Comment: Dave, that's not correct. The first iteration reads the first byte and yields the first bit. At that point, execution is paused inside the inner for-loop. The next iteration will resume from that point and will yield the next bit from the first byte. The next byte will only be read after the inner for-loop has finished (i.e. after 8 iterations).

Comment: @TommyCarlier See https://dotnetfiddle.net/Syk1kL - your solution skips ahead to the next byte with subsequent calls to `ReadBits`.

Comment: @Dave I'm sorry, I misunderstood your statement. Now I understand. But why would you call ReadBits multiple times? Even if you want to support that case, your solution has a problem if you call ReadBits on multiple Streams at the same time (e.g. from multiple threads). I'll add a comment to your solution with more details.

Comment: @TommyCarlier A couple of examples of needing to call the iterator multiple times would be to parse bit-packed fields in a file header or for operating on bits in a compressed stream. Also, thank you for the feedback on my answer - I thought the iterator state machines were generated separately per Stream instance but I will double-check :)

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible with the default stream class.  The C# (BCL) Stream class operates on the granularity of bytes at it's lowest level.  What you can do is write a wrapper class which reads bytes and partititions them out to bits.

For example:

```
class BitStream : IDisposable {
  private Stream m__stream;
  private byte? m_current;
  private int m_index;
  public byte ReadNextBit() { 
    if ( !m_current.HasValue ) {
      m_current = ReadNextByte();
      m_index = 0;
    }
    var value = (m_byte.Value >> m_index) & 0x1;
    m_index++;
    if (m_index == 8) {
      m_current = null;
    }
    return value;
  }
  private byte ReadNextByte() {
    ...
  }
  // Dispose implementation omitted
}
```

Note: This will read the bits in right to left fashion which may or may not be what you're intending.

Comment: @Alon, I just added a quick sample on how to do that

Comment: May you add a example for writing bits, please?

Comment: Streams are IDisposable: any wrapper such as BitStream should either be itself IDisposable, or (less preferably) explicitly document the fact that it does not deal with Disposal.

Comment: And when you run out of bits in the current byte you need a way to signal that the next byte needs to be read... Don't you hate it when your illustrative example starts to be real code that you'll never use personally.  :-)

Comment: @Alon -- people here tend to frown on the "will you write the code for me" type questions and comments.  You really should be able work out how to write bits given this code sample.  You just need to accumulate them into a byte until the byte is full, then write the byte.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to retrieve separate sections of your byte stream a few bits at a time, you need to remember the position of the bit to read next between calls. The following class takes care of caching the current byte and the bit position within it between calls.

```
// Binary MSB-first bit enumeration.
public class BitStream
{
    private Stream wrapped;
    private int bitPos = -1;
    private int buffer;

    public BitStream(Stream stream) => this.wrapped = stream;

    public IEnumerable<bool> ReadBits()
    {
        do
        {
            while (bitPos >= 0)
            {
                yield return (buffer & (1 << bitPos--)) > 0;
            }
            buffer = wrapped.ReadByte();
            bitPos = 7;  
        } while (buffer > -1);
    }
}
```

Call like this:

```
var bStream = new BitStream(<existing Stream>);
var firstBits = bStream.ReadBits().Take(2);
var nextBits = bStream.ReadBits().Take(3);
...
```

Comment: This solution has a problem: it keeps only 1 static instance of the buffer and bitPos variables. When you call ReadBits on multiple Streams at the same time (e.g. from multiple threads), the buffer and bitPos will not correctly work for those different Streams. Also, if you call ReadBits on 1 Stream, finish, and call ReadBits on a new Stream, the buffer and bitPos will still keep stale data from the previous Stream.

Comment: Yes, the extension method code had limitations because all fields must be static, disallowing you from interleaving reads for different `Stream`s you have open at the same time. I've turned the code into a regular wrapper class instead. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

For your purpose, I wrote an easy-to-use, fast and open-source (MIT license) library for this, called "BitStream", which is available at github (https://github.com/martinweihrauch/BitStream).

In this example, you can see how 5 unsigned integers, which can be represented with 6 bits (all below the value 63) are written with 6 bits each to a stream and then read back. Please note that the library takes and returns long or ulong values for the ease of it, so just convert your e. g. int, uint, etc to long/ulong first.

```cs
using SharpBitStream;

uint[] testDataUnsigned = { 5, 62, 17, 50, 33 };
var ms = new MemoryStream();
var bs = new BitStream(ms);
Console.WriteLine("Test1: \r\nFirst testing writing and reading small numbers of a max of 6 bits.");

Console.WriteLine("There are 5 unsigned ints , which shall be written into 6 bits each as they are all small than 64: 5, 62, 17, 50, 33");
foreach(var bits in testDataUnsigned)
{
    bs.WriteUnsigned(6, (ulong)bits);
}

Console.WriteLine("The original data are of the size: " + testDataUnsigned.Length + " bytes. The size of the stream is now: " + ms.Length + " bytes\r\nand the bytes in it are: ");

ms.Position = 0;

Console.WriteLine("The resulting bytes in the stream look like this: ");
for (int i = 0; i < ms.Length; i++)
{
    uint bits = (uint)ms.ReadByte();
    Console.WriteLine("Byte #" + Convert.ToString(i).PadLeft(4, '0') + ": " + Convert.ToString(bits, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));
}

Console.WriteLine("\r\nNow reading the bits back:");
ms.Position = 0;
bs.SetPosition(0, 0);

foreach (var bits in testDataUnsigned)
{
    ulong number = (uint)bs.ReadUnsigned(6);
    Console.WriteLine("Number read: " + number);
}
```